# Bash script to swap file locations, files with same names

Tags: bash, dictionary

I have a bunch of .mov video in a folder on my mac:

```
Documents/MyMovs
├── SubFolder01
│   ├── SubSubFolder01
│   │   ├── MyFile1.mov
│   │   ├── MyPdf.pdf
│   │   └── MyTxt.txt
│   └── SubSubFolder02
│       ├── MyFile2.mov
│       ├── MyPdf.pdf
│       └── MyTxt.txt
etc.
```

Using HandBrake I converted all of them to .mp4 but HandBrake put them all in Movies/

```
Movies
├── MyFile1.mp4
├── MyFile2.mp4
etc.
```

What I want to do is swap the files and get the exact reverse situation where all my mp4 are stored (at the correct location) in Documents/MyMovs and all mov files are in Movies/ where I will be able to delete them eventually.

at the end I want:

```
Documents/MyMovs
    ├── SubFolder01
    │   ├── SubSubFolder01
    │   │   ├── MyFile1.mp4
    │   │   ├── MyPdf.pdf
    │   │   └── MyTxt.txt
    │   └── SubSubFolder02
    │       ├── MyFile2.mp4
    │       ├── MyPdf.pdf
    │       └── MyTxt.txt
    etc.
```

and

```
  Movies
    ├── MyFile1.mov
    ├── MyFile2.mov
    etc.
```

I've designed the following bash script to help me (although I have the time to do it by hand due to the coronavirus crisis):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

MOV_DIR=$1
MP4_DIR=$2

declare -A FILES=( )

find $MOV_DIR -maxdepth 3 -name '*.mov' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
        filename=$(basename "$line")
        extension="${filename##*.}"
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        path_to_file=$(dirname "$line")
        if [[ ! -v FILES[$filename] ]]; then
          FILES[$filename]="$path_to_file"
          #echo $FILES[$filename] prints something!
        fi
    done

#for k in "${!FILES[@]}"; do echo "$k - ${FILES[$k]}"; done  ## prints nothing!

find $MP4_DIR -maxdepth 3 -name '*.mp4' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
        filename=$(basename "$line")
        extension="${filename##*.}"
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        path_to_file=$(dirname "$line")
        if [[ ! -z ${FILES["$filename"]} ]]; then
            mv "$path_to_file/$filename.mp4" "${FILES[$filename]}"
            mv "${FILES[$filename]}/filename.mov" "$path_to_file"
            #I would like to remove $filename from FILES as well but I don't know how
        fi
    done
```

Let's assume all filenames are unique and distinct from each other for simplicity.

I put all my mov files in a map filename -> path_to_filename; for example MyFile1 -> Documents/MyMovs/SubFolder01/SubSubFolder01 . This is the first find block.

Secondly I find all my mp4 files and retrieve the correct location using the map.

The code does not work it seems the map is local to the first find command and does not exist after. Would anybody know why? I use bash version 5.0.16(1)-release. Thanks everybody!

PS: I you have a completely different but better solution feel free to share

Comment: I feel you are complicating it too much... 1. Are other files (such as pdf and txt) to be ignored? 2. Do you want to preserve the directory structure? I.e., do you want `Movies/Subfolder1/Subsubfolder1/file1.mov` or `Movies/file1.mov`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one file, then find the other

```
find Documents -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 3 -name '*.mov' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' mov; do
        # extract the filename without extension
        name=$(basename "$mov" .mov)
        # find exactly the same name in Movies but with mp4
        mp4="Movies/$name.mp4"
        if [[ ! -f "$mp4" ]]; then
                echo "ERROR: File $mp4 does not exists" >&2
                exit 2
        fi
        # switch mp4 with mov
        movdir=$(dirname "$mov")
        mp4dir=$(dirname "$mp4")
        echo mv -v "$mp4" "$movdir"
        echo mv -v "$mov" "$mp4dir"
done
```

With the following directory/file recreation:

```
# find -type f
./Documents/MyMovs/Subfolder01/SubSubFolder01/MyFile1.mov
./Documents/MyMovs/Subfolder01/SubSubFolder02/MyFile2.mov
./Movies/MyFile1.mp4
./Movies/MyFile2.mp4
```

outputs:

```
mv -v Movies/MyFile1.mp4 Documents/MyMovs/Subfolder01/SubSubFolder01
mv -v Documents/MyMovs/Subfolder01/SubSubFolder01/MyFile1.mov Movies
mv -v Movies/MyFile2.mp4 Documents/MyMovs/Subfolder01/SubSubFolder02
mv -v Documents/MyMovs/Subfolder01/SubSubFolder02/MyFile2.mov Movies
```

> does not exist after. Would anybody know why?

Because the right side of `|` is run in a subshell. Parent shell doesn't know anything about child shell environment.

```
$ echo | { a=1; echo a=$a; }
a=1
$ echo a=$a
a=
```